# There is a bug when I extract audio feature using Opensmile

Tags: machine-learning, audio, deep-learning, feature-extraction, audeering-opensmile

I want to extract the feature from audio using OPENSMILE with the following cmd in Linux:

```
/iflytek/workplace/tools/opensmile/SMILExtract -C
/iflytek/workplace/tools/opensmile/config/gemaps/eGeMAPSv01a.conf -I
/iflytek/ytwei7/Coding/最新音频处理版本/音频切分/cut/1.wav -csvoutput
/iflytek/ytwei7/Coding/最新音频处理版本/特征提取/corpus/1.csv
```

And get an error:

```
(ERROR) [1] in configManager : ConfigType::findFieldH: referenced base field with name 
'Percentiles.quartiles' not found!
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Comment: Yes, thank you for removing that.

Answer (score 0):

I update GCC-version from 4.8 to 9.3 and compile opensmile in another way,the problem has gone. I don't know why but it works.